# LLBLGEN, how to update an existing entity

Tags: llblgen

1. I have entity Customer under group name Customers
2. I moved the Customer entity to a new group TestCustomers
3. The Customer db table changes in the meantime renaming a field from LastName to Surname
4. I do a Refresh Relational Model Data from a Database in the Catalog Explorer
5. No changes can be seen in my TestCustomers\Customer entity as it still has a field named LastName

Is this because the Designer has some kind of binding between it and the old entity path Customers\Customer?

How can I achieve the update I want?

Answer (score 1):

In LLBLGen Pro v3.5 you can try this:

In the Entity Editor, click on the Field mappings tab.
Click the Remove mapping button.
Click the Create mapping button.
Choose the correct target from the dropdown list.

This should re-create your entity including any new fields in your target db table.

There is also the Reverse-engineer unmapped target fields which can be used for this, but I found it was disabled for my entities until I remapped them. See documentation here:

http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.1/Designer/Functionality%20Reference/TypedViewEditor_FieldMappingsTab.htm